# How to view full site in mobile devices instead of mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

When viewing my site on mobile device, the site is automatically viewed in mobile version, like the image i have attached below

[image: my site]

But i need to view it in desktop view like the image below.

[image: site My customer]

In other words, how to disable mobile view when the site is viewed in mobile device and use the desktop view instead?

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Have you added any api for mobile device?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16532471/2469456) answer, the section that explains viewport explains what you want.

Comment: my site: http://ckf.net.au/ (need edit)
my customer site:http://www.ckfservices.com.au/Cleaning/ (example)
I have add meta tag: 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/> <!--320-->

Comment: remove that tag, it used when your site is responsive ready. by removing viewport meta tag it'll showed up as normal site.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell with the information given, but perhaps you're using the meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

If you have something like that in your code, remove it. If your website isn't designed to be responsive, then adding in the meta viewport tag will awkwardly zoom users in.

Comment: thanks you so much. I have remove all old meta view port then add
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: this fixed my issue in an responsive angular app that switched to a weird mobile design before.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your side responsive, you can manually set a width for the viewport. Add a meta tag like this into your html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

where 1024 should be a width that your site looks good. With this number, you can fine tune the appearance of your site.

Also remember to remove any other viewport definitions(especially any `width=device-width`).

You may have a look at this article: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design .

Comment: Thanks! I have <meta name="viewport" content="width=320"> and clear cache on brower.
Then change <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">.

Comment: @LoiHoang You are welcome. Just remove the meta line, or change width to a large number fit for you need.

Answer (score 1):

If your desire is just to view it in desktop mode / full site for testing (that's what it sounds like to me) and not permanently disable mobile view, than a number of browsers support Desktop view: Android Chrome -> tap on the top right three dots, select 'Request desktop site'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this `metadata` ,just remove it and the site won't be responsive

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

otherwise you can add `metadata` for setting your `viewport` size :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=your-size-in-number">
```

> You may want to read [Responsive Web Design - The Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)