# jQuery when zoom change css function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `top: x` for align an item to center of the screen.

Exemple:

```
div {
   top: 50%;
}
```

I would like a script when the screen size shrinks, to resize `top: 50%` by a certain percentage for example `0.2`.

Exemple:

If screen size is 1920 x 1080 `top: 50%;`
If zoom or change device with a smaller one and screen size is 320 x 480 `top: 45%;`

Every time when screen get smaller then 1920 x 1080 top get a value with - 0.01%

### Update

I use fittext.js and now it's work fine on every device at any screen resolution. It is a very useful plugin.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to make a js solution

you have to do something linke this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   $('#content').css("top", $(window).width() + somevar ); 
   //plus or minus something according to your requirments
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 1):

it can be done with media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
  div {
   top: 50%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  div {
   top: 45%;
  }
}
```

make sure you have added following in `head` to support media queries

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True"/>
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: elegant answer, but I have to disagree about the meta tags - the only one required is viewport, the others apparently are legacy / proprietary tags that aren't required - more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988499/meta-tags-for-mobile-should-they-be-used

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as stated, you could bind an event to [`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize) which could test the window width or height, and update the CSS of your element when it hits certain thresholds.

However, a *much* better solution would be to center it in a way that doesn't need adjusting - not to mention that javascript should not be used to fix display issues.

A good way to do this, when you know the height of your element, is to use `top:50%` and a negative `margin-top` of half the element's height.

There are other ways too, for example see the answers to [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers), or the [centering in css article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) on CSS tricks.