# HTML and CSS mobile content zoomed in?

Tags: html, css

Hello I have created a website: Omicrome.com The desktop version works find bar a few things I am still working out that are irrelevant. When I go onto the mobile version everything is zoomed in. If I dont set the viewport and put in:

```
   <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>
```

The content fits the way I want it on my Android HTC one m9. I run a "is my site mobile friendly test" and It says it isn't mobile friendly because I have not set the viewport and the content dosnt fit the screen, on my phone it does but on the image on those sites it is all zoomed in. If I do set the viewport then everything is zoomed in on my phone and on those websites. Here is a quick snippet of the head part of my page.

```
 <html class="HTML1">
<head>
   <title>Omicrome</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="img/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
   <link rel="ICON" href="img/icon.ico" type="image/ico" /> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960_24_col.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MobileStyle.css">
   <meta NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW">
   <meta name="description" CONTENT="The homepage for Omicrome.com, where you get the best of technology, science and making. We have on going projects and many articles for your enjoyment.">


 </head>
<body>


<div class = "container_24" style="min-height: 100%;">
   <header>....
```

Why does this happen and can I fix this. By the way I do have media queries for the css:

```
@media screen and (max-width:380px) {
    #HTML1{

    }
    #rectban{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 120px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        background: #ffffff;
    }

    #ULBTN{
        margin-top:-13px;
    }.....
```

I did try setting HTML1 to have a margin and padding of 0 and set their widths and heights to 100% but still it didnt work. Feel free to visit the page and tell me if it is zoomed in or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meta-tags for mobile – should they be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988499/meta-tags-for-mobile-should-they-be-used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
```

Comment: It should. Try to remove the handheldfriendly attribute. And look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988499/meta-tags-for-mobile-should-they-be-used

Comment: Ye I just read through that before posting here it dosnt help me and I did remove the handheldfriendly thing still no luck.

Comment: Could you supply an fiddle? I have suspicion that you are not telling us everything. Because it should work.

Comment: I took a look at the website http://omicrome.com/. And I think that there are some issues with your styles. There are rules like `min-width: 1200px;` which are applied on mobile. And that could be the reason why it is all "zoomed in". Do you use `em` and `rem` for sizing?

Comment: i dont use em or rem

Comment: should i get rid of the min widths?

Comment: When I opened the site in mobile view the mentioned rule was applied, and it should not, because I think that the resolution of your mobile is not `1200px`. And when you want to make your site responsive you should use `em` or `rem` units not pixels.

Comment: I just found this in a weird file that i didnt know was there. Its called 960_24_col.ccs it had body{min-wdith:960px;} I rmoved it and everything is messed up but at least viewport works now so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper mobile `viewport` declaration:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Can we get a live example or a fiddle? Tag I provided is the one you should be using instead of handheld friendly. Something else must be the issue, not this tag.